# C# логер Serilog. Настроить запись в файл с ограничением и по размеру файла и по количеству дней

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Здравствуйте использую логирование через Serilog для Asp net core 2.2 проекта.

Один из Sink-ов пишет в файл.

```
            .WriteTo.File("logs/Main_Log.txt",
                LogEventLevel.Information,
                rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,             //за 10 последних дней хранится Information лог (100МБ лимит размера файла)
                retainedFileCountLimit: 10,
                fileSizeLimitBytes: 100000000,                   
                rollOnFileSizeLimit: true)
```

Я хочу хранить информацию за 10 последних дней, независимо от того сколько файлов будет в один день.
Ограничение на размер файла 100мб.
Пока это ограничение соблюдалось для каждого дня, так и было каждый день было по 1 файлу и глубина логирования 10 файлов (10 дней). Но с ростом нагрузки в день стало по 10 фалов и стал писаться 1 день.

Answer (score -1):

Думаю, вам нужно пересчитать `fileSizeLimitBytes` и установить значение равное 1Gb.

Comment: Переведите пожалуйста ваше сообщение на русский язык.